# Make an asynchronous Artisan::call on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, lumen

I have an HTTP endpoints written in lumen and deployed on heroku which is calling Artisan::call("queue:work"...) to start processing some queue jobs.

```
 public function startProcess(Request $request)
    {
     
        Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--stop-when-empty', '--max-jobs' => 1]);
        return 'ok';
        
    }
```

As heroku allows a max timeout of 30 seconds, the process is failing as Artisan::call is synchronous, is there any way to make it asynchronous ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue processing after returning the response, if that is what you want:

```
    public function startProcess(Request $request)
    {
        // dont abort script execution if client disconnect
        ignore_user_abort(true);

        // dont limit the time
        set_time_limit(0);

        // turn on output buffering
        ob_start();

        // prepare the response

        // send the response
        return 'ok';
        header('Connection: close');
        header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
        // turn off output buffering
        ob_end_flush();
        // flush system output buffer
        flush();

        // continue processing
        Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--stop-when-empty', '--max-jobs' => 1]);
    }
```